# Set global template variable in template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know that there are context processors that can do this, but I want to set global template variable in template tag. So far I tried this:

```
class SetNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, key, nodelist):
        self.key = key
        self.nodelist = nodelist

    def render(self, context):
        value = self.nodelist.render(context)
        for d in context.dicts:
            d[self.key] = value
        return ''
```

I.e. iterate over all contexts and set variable, but it does not work. Can anyone explain how to do this? For example, base.html:

```
{{ my_var }} {# I want to set this variable in child template #}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

child.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% set my_var %}Hello{% endset %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an oldie-but-a-goodie: the [{% expr %}](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/) tag. The code is self-explanatory.

Note that using it (possibly) moves some of your business logic into your template, but sometimes that is OK.

Comment: I did not tryied it, but as I see variable will be available only inside it block. But I want set variable for all parent blocks (contexts too).

Comment: @Vladimir Mihailenco: Then look at the code and change it so that it walks farther up the stack of contexts and saves the value there. I'll warn you, though, that by doing that you will probably be setting yourself up (or someone who comes after you) for a truly evil debugging session as you try to figure out what the h*ll is happening to this one template variable's value.

Comment: my code already does it ("walks farther up the stack of contexts and saves the value there"), but it does not work. As I understand Django already renders parent/super template, when my tag got called. Do I miss something?